# Should I use constructor or method for deserealization Json to List<Map>?

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart and Json. I would like to write simple app that convert Json to List of Map. And get something like:

`[{id: 1, name: "mike"}, {"id": 2, "name": "piter"} ]`

from

`[{"id" : 1 , "name" : "mike", "code" : "01"}, {"id" : 2 , "name" : "piter", "code" : "02"}];`

I wrote some code. But I am not sure should I create instance of class in every iteration, or there is better way?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

main() async
{
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> MyJsonString =  [{"id" : 1 , "name" : "mike", "code" : "01"}, {"id" : 2 , "name" : "piter", "code" : "02"}];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> result;

  for(Map str in MyJsonString)
  {
    MyClass mc = MyClass.fromJson(str);
    // .... here 
  }
}

class MyClass
{
  int id;
  String name;

  MyClass(this.id, this.name);
  MyClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson()
  {
    return ({ 'id': id, 'name': name });
  }
}
```

And do I need constructor in this code? Or I could use just method? The code is based on example from docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you query correctly. One way to accomplish this would be

```
result = MyJsonString.map((item) => MyClass.fromJson(item).toJson()).toList();
```

Comment: I am getting error: ` Error: A value of type 'List<MyClass>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'.`

Comment: This is working:
`result = MyJsonString.map((item) => MyClass.fromJson(item).toJson()).toList();`

Comment: the idea was to use List<MyClass>, since fgrom the same code it seemed like you were interested in values of MyClass. But have updated the answer as you have mentioned now.